# How to make slider value change object or function?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audio, avfoundation

I am new to the site and Swift so any feedback on question technique is gratefully received.

I am trying to make the value of a slider change both the audio that it being played and the text label (or image).

I have created my outlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var audioSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var audioValue: UILabel!
```

And my action:

```
@IBAction func audioSliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = (sender.value)
    audioValue.text = (StringInterpolationConvertible: audioValue))
```

All connected to one slider. I am unsure of how to approach this issue - would an if else work?

**EDIT: Han Yong Code:**

There was already a 'do' for other sounds within the app using AVFoundation. I imported Foundation (AVFoundation was already imported)

I have added:

```
@IBOutlet weak var audioSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var audioValue: UILabel!
var audioSliderPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var currentTime: Double {
    get {
        return CMTimeGetSeconds(audioSliderPlayer.currentTime)
    }
    set {
        let newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(newValue, 1)
        audioSliderPlayer.seekToTime(newTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
    }
}
```

And added the following after the do function (within viewDidLoad):

```
    {timeObserverToken = audioSliderPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(interval, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        [weak self] time in
        self?.timeSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time))
        }}


}
```

I have updated the action:

```
@IBAction func timeSliderDidChange(sender: UISlider) {
    currentTime = Double(sender.value)
}
```

However, I am still having issues with errors. Also, how would I be able to specify which audio it plays dependent on value?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the `audioValue.text` show the same value of slider, right?
Try this:

```
@IBAction func audioSliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = (sender.value)
    audioValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```

Comment: No it shouldn't show the value of the slider - it should show text that changes dependent on the value

Answer (score 0):

If you use AVFoundation and AVPlayer, [sample source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Listings/Swift_AVFoundationSimplePlayer_iOS_PlayerViewController_swift.html) that apple provide will be helpful.

In this source, assign var that has get and set method. In set method, update your label and player state. (Sample source snippet don't update label, but you can make it.)

```
var currentTime: Double {
    get {
        return CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    }
    set {
        let newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(newValue, 1)
        player.seekToTime(newTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
    }
}
```

If slider changed, it trigger variable's set method. Label and player status will be updated.

```
@IBAction func timeSliderDidChange(sender: UISlider) {
    currentTime = Double(sender.value)
}
```

Add addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval method to AVPlayer. It will be called every interval you set and trigger your variable's setter.

```
timeObserverToken = player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(interval, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        [weak self] time in
        self?.timeSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion Han - I have further questions - please see the edit in the original post

Comment: I want to know about the error arisen. You need to change audio start time as slider is changed. Is it right?

Comment: 1. In the 'get', there is an error with the return - 'Cannot convert value of type NSTimeInterval' for the .currentTime
2. seekToTime is not being recognised as a member of AVAudioPlayer
3. timeObserverToken is coming up with unresolved identifier

Therefore the project will not build

The audio needs to change completely to another track when the value of the slider is changed.

Might it be better to do a 'do function with AVAudioSession?

Comment: My answer was based on AVPlayer. It is different with AVAudioPlayer. You'd better refer [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer). SeekToTime method in example should be changed to play(atTime: TimeInterval). Try out document.